# Replace function in a child theme

Tags: theme-development, functions, actions, child-theme

Is there a way to replace a function by another function in a child theme?
In other words, in a theme there is a function named "theme_function" and this function is called by several files inside the theme.
I would like to find, if exist, an action that replace all occurrences of "theme_function" with another function "child_function" inside the child theme.
Please note that "theme_function" that I want to replace do not have the following block:

```
if ( !function_exists('theme_function') ) :
```

because if it that case is easy to replace the theme_function with another function having the same name in functions.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parent-Theme function in question isn't either pluggable (i.e. wrapped in a `if( ! function_exists( $function ) )` conditional) or filterable (i.e. returns its output wrapped in a `apply_filters( $filtername, $output )`), then there's no easy way to override the function.

You'll have to do one of the following:

1. Replace all template files that contain instances of the function call, and replace those calls with your own child-Theme function, in all such templates
2. Modify the parent Theme, to delete (or make pluggable) the function in question

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that there was a method to do it, but the only way is to contaminate the parent theme or to replace a lot of files containing the function call in the child theme.

Comment: If the parent Theme developer is amenable to patches, you could always modify the parent Theme to make the file pluggable, and then submit the change back to the developer, as a patch.

Comment: Infact! Because the best way, always, is to make the functions pluggable.

Comment: Actually, I prefer making my functions *filterable*, in almost all cases. :)